# Computing the invariant factors and elementary divisors of finitely generated module over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

I have just encountered this question in my abstract algebra class dealing with finitely generated modules over PIDs stating the following:

> Let $ D = \mathbb{R}[x] $ be the ring of polynomials over the reals in variable $x$, and let $M$ be a $D$-module with elements $ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in M $ such that $ M = Dv_1 \oplus Dv_2 \oplus Dv_3 \oplus Dv_4 $, satisfying:
> $\mathrm{ann}(v_1) = (x-1)^3 $; $\mathrm{ann}(v_2) = (x^2+1)^2$; $\mathrm{ann}(v_3) = (x-1)(x^2+1)^4$; $\mathrm{ann}(v_4) = (x+2)(x^2+1)^2 $. We are now asked to find the invariant factors and elementary divisors of $M$. (Jacobson, *Basic Algebra I*, Exercise 3.9.1)

Now all I know is that M is a finitely generated cyclic module over a PID as the direct sum of cyclic modules and I know the fundamental theorems on finitely generated modules over PIDs but I do not know how to extract the invariant factors and elementary divisors from the statement above, so I am hoping for some help on this with a bit of explanation, thanks all helpers

Comment: Do you know how to do this for finitely generated modules over $\mathbb Z$, (abelian groups)?

Comment: @JohnBrevik No I do not as I have never extracted this information in the past and do not know how to do this

Comment: I think that would be the right place to start. Whatever text you are using must do this somewhere.

Comment: I use Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra but did not find this

Comment: Look in Section 5.2 :)

Comment: @JohnBrevik OK I got the integer case now but how exactly to adapt this for our case involving polynomials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33998/discussion-between-john-brevik-and-zbigniew2015).

Answer (score 2):

you are given a cyclic decomposition (one generator for each summand).  the elementary divisors arise from a cyclic, prime power, decomposition.  hence you only have to factor all your anihilators into prime powers.  That gives $x+2$, $(x-1)$, $(x-1)^3$, $(x^2+1)^2$, $(x^2+1)^2$, $(x^2+1)^4$.  Now to get the invariant factors arrange these as relatively prime products in the only possible way so they successively divide each other.  That is,
$(x^2+1)^2$, $(x-1)(x^2+1)^2$, $(x+2)(x-1)^3(x^2+1)^4$.  voila'.