# Module elementary divisors.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, smith-normal-form

> I am practicing for myself how to find all possible elementary divisors and the corresponding invariant factors for an $R$-module of order $(x-1)^3(x +1)^2$ where $R = k[x]$ and $k$ is a field.

But it is not very much clear in my mind what are the steps for doing that. I know that at some step I would find the characteristic polynomial of degree 1,2,3 or 1,2 (or maybe I am wrong in that). I  think I understand how to find elementary divisors for abelian groups, but how that leads me to the way of finding it for modules?

I have read the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603884) but still I do not understand what I can do in my case as the givens in my problem are different.

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The elementary divisors are:

Since the elementary divisors are all combinations of the prime ideals we have, then they are:

1-$\{ (x-1), (x-1), (x-1), (x+1), (x+1)\}$

2-$\{ (x-1),(x-1)^2, (x+1), (x+1)\}$

3-$\{(x-1)^3, (x+1), (x+1)\}$

4-$\{ (x-1), (x-1), (x-1), (x+1)^2\}$

5-$\{ (x-1), (x-1)^2, (x+1)^2\}$

6-$\{(x-1)^3,(x +1)^2\}$

**Sorry I wrote them before seeing the answer below, thanks @user26857**

And the corresponding invariant factors are:

1-$\{(x-1), (x-1)(x+1), (x-1)(x+1),\}$

2-$\{(x-1)(x+1), (x-1)^2(x+1) \}$

3-$\{(x+1), (x-1)^3(x+1)\}$

4-$\{(x-1), (x-1), (x-1)(x+1)^2\}$

5-$\{(x-1)^2, (x-1)(x+1)^2, (x-1)^2\}$

6-$\{ (x-1), (x-1)^2(x+1)^2\}$

7-$\{(x-1)^3(x+1)^2\}$

Comment: What is a module of order $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$? Does it mean the annihilator of the module is generated by $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$?

Comment: @mathmath the order of a module is the product of its prime ideals.

Comment: For finding elementary divisors, you want to sort of "partition" $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$ into product of power of linear forms (prime ideals). Notice that you may have more than one way to do that and each way will give you a different module. For example, one way is $(x-1),(x-1),(x-1),(x+1),(x+1)$, another way is $(x-1),(x-1)^2,(x+1),(x+1)$ and so on.

Comment: For each list of elementary divisors, for each linear form, take the highest degree and multiply them all (and remove them from the list), for example, for the first one, you will get the invariant factors $(x-1),(x-1)(x+1),(x-1)(x+1)$. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think so @mathmath thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the elementary divisors. There are six possibilities corresponding to the partitions of the exponents, three for $3$ and two for $2$, that is,
$x-1,x-1,x-1,x+1,x+1$
$x-1,x-1,x-1,(x+1)^2$
$x-1,(x-1)^2,x+1,x+1$
$x-1,(x-1)^2,(x+1)^2$
$(x-1)^3,x+1,x+1$
$(x-1)^3,(x+1)^2$

I am confident that you can find the invariant factors in each case.

Comment: Yeah sure I can.

Comment: I have a quick question (if you do not mind).  In the case of groups, the invariant factors are the combinations of prime factors when all coprime numbers are multiplied from elementary divisors, but here are all prime ideals coprime? and also, in the case of groups, if a number $x$ has prime factorization $p_1^2 p_2$ then the Invariant factors include $p_1^2 p_2$ only if  $p_1^2 > p_2,$ how is that done incase of modules here?

Comment: The answer to the first question is positive. But I'm afraid I don't understand the second one. Can't be $3^2\cdot 11$ and invariant factor? Why? If the elementary divisors are 9 and 11, then which are the invariant factors?

Comment: Ok.thanks for the answer to the first question. I see your point in my second question, It seems like I was wrong in my statement.

Comment: I edited my question with the invariant factors where I got 5 and 6 from the elementary divisor 5. are my 5th and 6th invariant factors correct? Is my list is the whole list of invariant factors?

Comment: @mathmusic How did you get seven sets of invariant factors out of six sets of elementary divisors? The fifth set of invariant factors seems to be out of nowhere.

Comment: Ok. I got you now, thank you!